# Is CMOVcc considered a branching instruction?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, cpu-architecture, micro-optimization, branch-prediction

I have this `memchr` code that I'm trying to make non-branching:

```
.globl memchr
memchr:
        mov %rdx, %rcx
        mov %sil, %al
        cld
        repne scasb
        lea -1(%rdi), %rax
        test %rcx, %rcx
        cmove %rcx, %rax
        ret
```

I'm unsure whether or not `cmove` is a branching instruction. Is it? If so, how do I rearrange my code so it doesn't branch?

Comment: You don't need `cld`; all the standard calling conventions guarantee/require DF=0 on call/ret.  Also, `movzbl %sil, %eax` would be more efficient than merging into the low byte of RAX.  Or just `mov %esi, %eax` is good except if you caller only wrote AL on a P6-family CPU.

Comment: I assume downvoted for lack of research effort.  e.g. google for `is cmov a branch` has several hits which all make it obvious, including [Why is a conditional move not vulnerable for Branch Prediction Failure?](//stackoverflow.com/q/14131096) (which is a possible duplicate).  I don't think there's any real way to improve the question.  Including any specific wrong claims or misleading sources would just lead to a more bloated answer that refutes them.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, it's not a branch, that's the whole point of `cmovcc`.

**It's an ALU select that has a data dependency on *both* inputs, not a control dependency**.  (With a memory source, [it unconditionally loads the memory source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54050188/hard-to-debug-segv-due-to-skipped-cmov-from-out-of-bounds-memory), unlike ARM predicated load instructions that are truly NOPed.  So you can't use it with maybe-bad pointers for branchless bounds or NULL checks.  That's maybe the clearest illustration that it's definitely not a branch.)

But anyway, it's not predicted or speculated in any way; as far as the CPU scheduler is concerned it's just like an `adc` instruction: 2 integer inputs + FLAGS, and 1 integer output.  (Only difference from `adc`/`sbb` is that it doesn't write FLAGS.  And of course runs on an execution unit with different internals).

Whether that's good or bad entirely depends on the use-case.  See also [gcc optimization flag -O3 makes code slower than -O2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28875325/gcc-optimization-flag-o3-makes-code-slower-than-o2) for much more about `cmov` upside / downside

---

**Note that `repne scasb` is not fast.**  "Fast Strings" only works for rep stos / movs.

`repne scasb` runs about 1 count per clock cycle on modern CPUs, i.e. typically about 16x worse than a simple SSE2 `pcmpeqb`/`pmovmskb`/`test+jnz` loop.  And with clever optimization you can go even faster, up to 2 vectors per clock saturating the load ports.

(e.g. see glibc's `memchr` for ORing `pcmpeqb` results for a whole cache line together to feed one `pmovmskb`, IIRC.  Then go back and sort out where the actual hit was.)

`repne scasb` also has startup overhead, but microcode branching is different from regular branching: it's not branch-predicted on Intel CPUs.  So this can't mispredict, but is total garbage for performance with anything but very small buffers.

SSE2 is baseline for x86-64 and efficient unaligned loads + `pmovmskb` make it a no-brainer for `memchr` where you can check for length >= 16 to avoid crossing into an unmapped page.

**Fast strlen**:

- [Why is this code 6.5x slower with optimizations enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55563598/why-is-this-code-6-5x-slower-with-optimizations-enabled/55589634#55589634) shows a simple not-unrolled strlen for 16-byte-aligned inputs using SSE2.
- [Why does glibc's strlen need to be so complicated to run quickly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57650895/why-does-glibcs-strlen-need-to-be-so-complicated-to-run-quickly/57676035#57676035) links to some more stuff about hand-optimized asm strlen functions in glibc.  (And how to make a bithack strlen in GNU C avoid strict-aliasing UB.)
- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/213558  scalar bithack strlen, including the same 4-byte-at-a-time bithack that the glibc question was about.  Better than byte-at-a-time but pointless with SSE2 (which x86-64 guarantees).  However, @CodyGray's tutorial-style answer may be a useful for beginners.  Note that it doesn't take into account [Is it safe to read past the end of a buffer within the same page on x86 and x64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800739/is-it-safe-to-read-past-the-end-of-a-buffer-within-the-same-page-on-x86-and-x64)

Comment: *"**Note that `repne scasb` is not fast.**"* -- I know. I'm planning on replacing it with something faster later, but for now it's small and it works.

Comment: I also don't have any experience with any SSE/2/3/4.1 stuff.

Comment: @JL2210: `memchr` is a pretty good way to learn about using SSE2 for simple element-match searching; knowing the size as a function arg (instead of implicit length) makes it significantly simpler than `strchr`.

Comment: @JL2210 You might be interested in [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/213558), which discusses ways of optimizing `strlen` using basic x86 instructions (i.e., without using any SSE). A similar approach could be used for `memchr`, except that you can't optimize so heavily around searching for a 0-byte. Certainly, as Peter says, SSE is the way to make it *really* fast. I've written and benchmarked that code, too. If you want to know more, ask more questions about it. I could expand that answer another 10 pages, but I'd eventually run out of room and folks would tire of reading.

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks for the offer.

Comment: @JL2210: Updated my answer with some links to SIMD strlen as described in this answer.  `memchr` using the zero-byte-in-word bithack usually just does an `xor` with the byte being searched for.  You can broadcast it with `c * 0x01010101UL` or whatever.

Comment: @JL2210: x86-64 guarantees availability of SSE2 for `pcmpeqb`.  If you need 4-byte or 8-byte chunks, `movd` or `movq`+`pcmpeqd` should beat a scalar bithack even in the no-false-positive case.  It's also pointless if you know SSE2 is available in 32-bit code, so updated my answer to say "with SSE2".

Comment: @PeterCordes Say I made a C version of that same code. Would it still be reasonably more efficient than a byte-for-byte loop?

Comment: @JL2210: Yes, for all but the shortest of strings, because current compilers (except ICC) can't auto-vectorize search loops.  But this is an assembly-language question.  But to make an `unsigned long` version without violating strict aliasing in C you'd need `memcpy` for the aliasing loads.  Or you could use Intel SIMD intrinscs.  Or using GNU C `typedef unsigned long aliasing_long __attribute((may_alias))`.  Although that would be useful for a *portable* version: [Why does glibc's strlen need to be so complicated to run quickly?](//stackoverflow.com/a/57676035)