# In C++, does the branch predictor predict implicit conditional statements?

Tags: c++, syntax, conditional-statements, branch-prediction

In this code, it is written, `result += runs[i] > runs[i-1];`, an implicit conditional statement. In C++, does the branch predictor make predictions for this statement? Or do I have to explicitly use the `if` keyword to get branch prediction going?

```
using namespace std; 
int progressDays(vector<int> runs) {
    if (runs.size() < 2) {return 0;}
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < runs.size(); i++) {result += runs[i] > runs[i-1];}
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I don't think the C++ language, per se, has such a thing as a "branch predictor".  Your particular CPU might have one, in which case whether it gets used would depend on whether the compiler generated code containing a branch, or not.  Many machines would have ways to do this without branching, and compilers tend to prefer those where possible.  Note that even if you do use the `if` keyword, the compiler is still equally free to generate branchless code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**CPUs don't run C++ directly, they run machine code.  So the answer depends on how your C++ compiles to assembly / machine code.**  Your choices for expressing program logic in C++ only indirectly influences this.  Modern compilers *can* and will do if-conversion of a C++ `if()` statement into asm without branches (aka branchless).  (For GCC, that's done more aggressively at `-O3` than at `-O2` - see [gcc optimization flag -O3 makes code slower than -O2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28875325/gcc-optimization-flag-o3-makes-code-slower-than-o2))

**One most architectures, there are efficient ways to turn a compare result into a 0 or 1 integer fairly directly**.  (Or branchlessly increment a different way, or even more directly, e.g. [AArch64's `csinc`](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0802/b/A64-General-Instructions/CSINC) / `csel` / `cinc` instruction which does a conditional increment, reading an input register and flags).  **So generally using `x < y` as an integer value will compile branchlessly.**

```
int conditional_inc(int x, int y, int z) {
    z += (x<y);
    return z;
}
```

For example, [on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tLry3oAMnlqYAcsYBGmYiADMpAA6oFhdbT1DEzMvHz86a1sHI2dXDyUVNToGAmZiAkDjUx5FZUxVfxS0gkj7Jxd3RVT0zOCchWqSmzKYircASkVUA2JkDgByGwIAajRtcNo2AH0bZAgh4YAPUmGFgE8VhYAvduHxAHZZAAYAQWHz4a29mXE3ABFhiEXbnTX22%2BOzi%2BJMAh7aS4fcSnA53fqdVggfoAVn6pFM/SOcNQUJ0cjkwwU3V6mGubk4cIIUKR7U6AGt3ABOAB03H2%2BwAHEcAGyMhnQzicfbQoRQ7hwhFI0go/pwhQgI6kImI8GkOCwGCIFCoIyePDsMgUCBoVXqirIYSiThHE2kKjqggucUQRzEuGOGxpNZQgmkHVGLQEADytFYzplpCwRhEwHYdsDeB%2BBQAbphxQHMIt8gZLS64UNlOHWHhHMQnXosGmpcQ8EY050aPQmGwODkBJwhCGUOiZEIc%2BLIJ1UJ4krR4wBaL1uMV5AoaCAWWrZUgWUrRWKCby%2BXtTxdhXtz8quBsJfK9oo1fRZQS7se0A9NKJbk%2BNVc7xqb1rbzpYnp9LgQqGw%2BHhkWLBnMv2zLcKMhrAMMxrUkcUGPLghAkHiDbDHouoaohuxojcMiEnapKkBS0KSpC/T8qQZZuNC1LMpSlKcNCkjQtwkhuPskgMgyP4BiKYoSlKuFyoqEBIDqaoauQlAiXqrhpEYwHAAykiSuarCWsQ1q2gGDqTMQ/quu6no%2Bn64ZBiGYYBvgUZqLG8ZComyapv0roZsRQrZrm%2BYYAMroECWZaObKlaMCwYZ1iAkiNqIzZYfIbkdhAXY9v4A5DiOiT%2BJo2h3jO2iPguDZLhMWUFRuzTzhUO6jvut5HnUuRpckD6lde97FFlDTFLl5Uvti76cJ%2BMICr%2BUInAASgAssBwzAMgyDDAy1KSLB%2BBEMQiErChokuHikgYS20g4TKeHEaRZbAdSbgmgydLcNC%2BzMpI%2BycpxQrcYovHSiS5IgMy0H0ZInCUm4/08OxDG8v0w7PciUIHZ94OSINXEw3xh2dLGanpdwQA%3D%3D%3D)

```
# x86-64 clang -O3
conditional_inc(int, int, int)
        xor     eax, eax        # prepare a zeroed register for setl of the low byte, to extend to 32-bit.  (x86 is annoyingly clunky and inefficient at this)
        cmp     edi, esi
        setl    al              # EAX = AL = (x<y) signed compare
        add     eax, edx        # EAX += z in the retval register
        ret
```

AArch64 is much more efficient, with a combined increment and select instruction replacing xor-zero/setcc/add.

```
conditional_inc(int, int, int):
        cmp     w0, w1           // compare
        cinc    w0, w2, lt       // use the flags result, and the other 2 inputs.
        ret
```

---

All of these, like x86-64 [`setcc`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/setcc), are just ALU instructions, not control (no conditional change to the program counter), so have a data dependency instead of a control dependency, and thus don't need branch prediction because there's no branching.   (The most well-known such instruction is probably x86 `cmovcc`, but in this case only `setcc` is needed)

- [Is CMOVcc considered a branching instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57524415/is-cmovcc-considered-a-branching-instruction)
- [Why is a conditional move not vulnerable for Branch Prediction Failure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131096/why-is-a-conditional-move-not-vulnerable-for-branch-prediction-failure/14131331#14131331) shows an asm example of using cmov to conditionally increment.

---

In general, compares are separate from to branching.  You can compare and then get a boolean without branching.  (Branches do need something to branch on, but that can be an implicit compare against zero of an integer or boolean.)

So **that's not a conditional statement**, it's just a boolean being used as an integer.