# Understanding fcmovb instruction in x86

Tags: assembly, x86, x87, conditional-move

I'm not understanding why `fcmovb st(0) st(4)` is not acting the way I expect. afaiu it will set `st0 = st4` if the `CF` flag is set.

Before:

```
gdb> i r eflags st0 st4
eflags 0x282 [ SF IF ]
st0 0 (raw 0x00...)
st4 0 (raw 0x00...)
```

After:

```
gdb> i r eflags st0 st4
eflags 0x282 [ SF IF ]
st0 -nan(0xc0...) (raw 0xffffc00...)
st4 0 (raw 0x00...)
```

What is going here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `st(4)` marked as "in use"?  e.g. have you done 5 `fld` operations yet?  If not, reading it is an invalid operation.  Check x87 status flag C1 to see if stack underflow happened: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/fcmovcc  .  (Apparently it's an ALU select operation that reads both inputs and then writes the output, so regardless of CF, it is trying to read `st4`.  Integer `cmov` works that way; an invalid memory operand will fault: [Hard to debug SEGV due to skipped cmov from out-of-bounds memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54050188))

Comment: Is that st0 bit-pattern the same as what you'd get from `fst st0, st4` if `st4` wasn't in use?  i.e. a NaN-indefinite.  http://www.ray.masmcode.com/tutorial/fpuchap2.htm#indefini .  Yeah, I think so: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#x86_extended_precision_format - top 2 bits of the 64-bit mantissa are set (`0xc`), rest are `0`.

Comment: how do i check if it was in use? how do i check hte x87 status flag? sorry it appears i need to learn more about x87 fpu...

Comment: Use `info float`

Comment: You can design your test case to push enough stuff on the x87 stack first.  To actually check, see http://www.ray.masmcode.com/tutorial/fpuchap1.htm for the internals including the x87 tag word.  GDB should be able to show it with `info reg float`.  Oh, yes and Jester's suggestion of `info float` decodes and pretty-prints stuff, showing which underlying regs are empty or not, and where the top-of-stack pointer is pointing (which one is st0)

Comment: Thanks Peter and Jester. I checked `info float` and indeed it marks r0 to r7 as empty. I'll see if I can dig from here.