# The Execution Order in an Assembly Algorithm that utilizes a Conditional Move Instruction

Tags: c++, assembly, x86-64, cpu-architecture, conditional-move

I have recently been working on an assembly algorithm for calculating the absolute difference between two long integers, and I have some concerns regarding the execution order in the presence of conditional move instructions. Below is a snippet of the assembly code in question:

```
.globl _start

_start:
    movq $3, %rsi # x
    movq $5, %rdi # y
    
    movq %rdi, %rax
    subq %rsi, %rdi
    subq %rax, %rsi
    cmovgq %rsi, %rdi
    
    movq $60, %rax
    syscall
```

In the provided assembly code, the `cmovgq` instruction is used to conditionally move the result of the subtraction (`x - y` or `y - x`) based on the outcome of a previous comparison (`x > y`). My concern is whether the processor executes the `cmovgq` instruction before waiting for the result from the subtraction (`subq %rax, %rsi`).

I am aware that there is no explicit data dependency between the subtraction instruction and the conditional move instruction. However, due to modern processors' pipelining behavior, I am uncertain about the potential issues that might arise.

To provide context, the corresponding C code for this assembly algorithm is as follows:

```
long absdiff(long x, long y) {
    long result = 0;
    // unpredictable branch
    if(x < y) {
        result = y - x;
    } else {
        result = x - y;
    }
    return result;
}
```

I would greatly appreciate any insights, explanations, or suggestions from the community regarding the execution order of these instructions and whether pipelining could introduce any issues in this algorithm.

Comment: Within a single thread (ie not involving memory that may be used by a hardware device, signal handler, or another thread) all the parallelism in the processor ultimately is resolved to match the operation order in the (dis)assembly source code. `cmov` has a dependency on the status flags written by the last arithmetic instruction(s). So the processor will only resolve its final result once the flags are "known".

Comment: If your C++ code is correct, then the code generated by the compiler will be too (assuming there is no bug in your compiler, which is very rare especially in such trivial case -- not to mention at least hundred of thousands of developers write codes like this regularly). You should not care about this unless you have found a bug, and you suspect the compiler to generate a bad code because you have explored all other solutions (i.e. desperate case). Here the code is legal and the generated code seems fine too. In fact, the choice to use a branchless instruction is good here.

Comment: Bug-free  HW will use the result of previous operations - inserting NOOP into the pipeline, if necessary. But the result of final instruction might be available before the previous data is written to cache.

Comment: BTW, I just edited my answer to add a couple links with some computer-architecture basics.  @Red.Wave's comment got me thinking in that direction because no current x86-64 CPUs use in-order execution, so "inserting NOPs" isn't even a thing that makes sense.  In some cycles, some ALU execution units don't get a uop dispatched to them, but NOPs in the instruction stream aren't directly like that.  It is how you might think about stalls in an in-order pipeline, though, maybe even a superscalar one like P5 (an x86-64 version of which was in Knight's Corner) or the old in-order x86-64 Atom.

Comment: @PeterCordes, in order execution is not what I meant. That would slow down the core. Regardless of the mechanism, CPU keeps track of hot data. A preprocesse step in pipelines reorders instructions to minimize stall; but sometimes there's no valid opcode to put inside the pipe. Some equivalent of NOOP might need to be pushed in the pipe when parallel processing is not possible.

Comment: @Red.Wave: In superscalar out-of-order exec CPUs, there isn't only one pipe.  See the block diagram in https://www.realworldtech.com/sandy-bridge/10/ ( and read the whole article, it's *excellent*.)  When there are no uops ready for an execution unit, it doesn't start work on one that cycle, but the separately pipelined execution units aren't what I'd call "the pipe".  And issue/rename stages doesn't feed NOPs into the ROB (Reorder Buffer) unless they were present in the machine code.  It might only be able to issue (Intel terminology) less than 4 uops in some cycles, but the rest aren't NOPs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`cmov` has 3 inputs: two registers (explicit operands), and FLAGS (implicit).**
Same as `adc` and `sbb`, except those also write FLAGS as an output.

The data dependency between `sub` writing FLAGS and `cmovg` reading it is every bit as real as between `sub` instructions writing `rsi` and `rdi` before `cmovg` reads them.
In formal terms, this is a RAW (Read After Write) data hazard which CPUs must respect.  See wikipedia for [classic RISC in-order pipelines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_RISC_pipeline#Data_hazards), and [data hazards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazard_(computer_architecture)) in general.

(All current x86-64 CPUs do out-of-order exec, where a scheduler keeps track of which values are ready, and thus which uops are ready to run if there's a free execution unit.  Register renaming avoids WAR and WAW hazards.  See [Modern Microprocessors
A 90-Minute Guide!](https://www.lighterra.com/papers/modernmicroprocessors/) and deep-dive breakdowns of real CPUs like [Sandybridge](https://www.realworldtech.com/sandy-bridge/), the first of what's still Intel's current family of big-core CPUs.)

**`cmov` isn't special, it's just an ALU select operation with 3 inputs and one output.**  Not like 32-bit ARM predicated instructions where a false predicate turns it into a NOP, so even a load from a bad address won't fault.  ([Unlike x86 `cmov`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54050188/hard-to-debug-segv-due-to-skipped-cmov-from-out-of-bounds-memory/54050427#54050427), but like APX `cfcmov`, conditionally-faulting cmov conditional load or store.)

---

**FLAGS is renamed just like other registers**, so CPUs respect data dependencies through FLAGS exactly the same as through integer registers.  A single register-file entry can hold an integer register and FLAGS, so the CPU can treat instructions like `sub` that write FLAGS and a register as having a single output.

A later instruction like LEA that writes a register but not FLAGS can leave just FLAGS pointing at the older physical register in the RAT (register allocation table), or an instruction like `cmc` or `add [mem], eax` that writes FLAGS but not a register would have to allocate a PRF entry for just FLAGS, and leave the old entry pointed-to by just the integer register.

---

**The cardinal rule of pipelined out-of-order exec is that a single thread runs *as if* the CPU ran one instruction at a time in program order.**  An instruction can always see the results of previous instructions, and never see the result of future instructions.  If this wasn't true, the CPU wouldn't correctly implement the ISA specification and couldn't run existing code.  i.e. the design would be buggy.

(I'm just talking about correctness here, not performance differences like cache conflict-misses caused by early exec of later loads that evicted data needed by a load whose address wasn't ready yet.  Microarchitectural state can depend on timing details; Spectre and other CPU vulnerabilities use timing to turn microarchitectural state into architectural state (long-term values in registers or memory))

---

A few ISAs have had execution models other than just 1 at a time in program order.  For example [VLIW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Very_long_instruction_word) machines expect the compiler (or asm programmer) to find 3 (for example) independent operations to put into one wide instruction-word, so the CPU doesn't have to check for dependencies or hazards between them.  And The Mill had loads that produce a value like 5 instructions from now (depending on the microarchitecture so you had to recompile if that changed). So you can keep reading the old value until then, but also hide some load latency.

For x86 (and current mainstream ISAs like RISC-V and AArch64), the execution model is indeed that instructions execute one at a time, in program order.  It's basically like the C++ as-if rule: internally it can do anything that results in the same register and memory values for a single thread.  Memory-ordering rules define what orderings of operations other threads looking at shared memory are or aren't allowed to see.  (Memory ordering is not the same thing as execution order, e.g. [store buffers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64141366/can-a-speculatively-executed-cpu-branch-contain-opcodes-that-access-ram) create memory reordering on their own, at least StoreLoad, even on an in-order CPU.  A store buffer is important for speculative execution of store instructions, among other things.)

Comment: I dont know how to thankyou! also the thanks for sharing that 90minute guide! I am learning computer architecture if you have any other recommendations too please kindly let me know.

Comment: @works: Agner Fog's guide to x86 microarchitectures is quite good, focused on things that are relevant for optimizing software for them.  https://agner.org/optimize/.  Other links in the x86 tag wiki https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info .   Other articles on realworldtech are *excellent*.  A more recent site, Chips and Cheese, has some interesting articles like https://chipsandcheese.com/2023/10/01/arms-cortex-a510-two-kids-in-a-trench-coat/ a look at a modern in-order efficiency core, comparing to the widespread Cortex A53.

Comment: Also Wikichip has some microarchitectural details, but isn't always 100% accurate.  Also https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/amd/microarchitectures/zen_2