# gcc 12 generate worse assemble code in finding the min element in a vector than gcc 8

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-optimization

Test code:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>
#include <algorithm>

uint32_t find_min(const std::vector<uint32_t>& v)
{
    return std::distance(v.begin(), std::min_element(v.begin(), v.end()));
}
```

Find the index of the min element in a vector.

GCC 8 generated code:

```
find_min(std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > const&):
        mov     rcx, QWORD PTR [rdi+8]
        mov     rsi, QWORD PTR [rdi]
        xor     eax, eax
        cmp     rcx, rsi
        je      .L1
        lea     rax, [rsi+4]
        mov     rdx, rsi
        cmp     rcx, rax
        je      .L4
.L6:
        mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rdx]
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rax], edi
        cmovb   rdx, rax
        add     rax, 4
        cmp     rcx, rax
        jne     .L6
.L4:
        mov     rax, rdx
        sub     rax, rsi
        sar     rax, 2
.L1:
        ret
```

GCC 12 generated code:

```
find_min(std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > const&):
        mov     r8, QWORD PTR [rdi+8]
        mov     rdi, QWORD PTR [rdi]
        xor     eax, eax
        cmp     rdi, r8
        je      .L1
        lea     rdx, [rdi+4]
        cmp     r8, rdx
        je      .L1
        mov     esi, DWORD PTR [rdi]
        mov     rax, rdi
.L4:
        mov     ecx, DWORD PTR [rdx]
        cmp     ecx, esi
        jnb     .L3
        mov     esi, ecx
        mov     rax, rdx
.L3:
        add     rdx, 4
        cmp     r8, rdx
        jne     .L4
        sub     rax, rdi
        sar     rax, 2
.L1:
        ret
```

Both compiler use `-O3` flag, use Compiler Explorer to generated these code: https://godbolt.org/z/ehv9Mv584

We can see GCC 8 generated code use `cmovb`, and GCC 12 generated code use a branch. In my real test, GCC 8 generated code run faster.

My question is, is there any way to let GCC 12 generate the similar assemble code like GCC 8, using `cmovb` rather than branch?

---

I found a solution, disable `-ftree-partial-pre` flag solve this problem:

```
uint32_t __attribute__((optimize("no-tree-partial-pre"))) find_min(const std::vector<uint32_t>& v) {....}
```

Can anybody help explain how partial redundancy elimination (PRE) work in this case?

Comment: PGO (profile guided optimization) should let GCC notice that the branch is unpredictable.  Related: [gcc optimization flag -O3 makes code slower than -O2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28875325) for another case of branchy vs. branchless looping over an array, where GCC makes a longer dep chain than necessary for the branchless version.  (And GCC7 even de-optimizes to that if you write it the better way in the source.)  -O2 vs. -O3 had an effect on whether GCC did if-conversion to branchless or not in that case at that time.

Comment: It seems to use `cmovb` with `-march=native` https://godbolt.org/z/Wqrr14f8E, hmm. I would experiment with different `-march=` values.

Comment: Also, it's unfortunate that GCC doesn't auto-vectorize this even with `-march=skylake` to make AVX2 available. :/  It's not nearly as easy as a simple reduction since it would have to invent a vector of counters and blend them as it's reducing the vector of mins, to know where the element came from.  But it could go maybe 8x faster in a non-tiny array that fits in L1d cache.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Godbolt runs on AWS instances that aren't always the same microarchitecture.  `-march=icelake-server` still branches; `-march=znver3` uses 2x `cmovb` which is probably what you saw.  This might be a case of poor tuning choices; CMOV on Intel since Broadwell is single-uop.  clang 16 makes branchless code with `-march=skylake` or other Intel, as well as AMD (but doesn't auto-vectorize either).  Anyway, so there's probably a knob somewhere that controls whatever heuristic is relevant in the cost model; many of those can be adjusted via obscure command line options.

Comment: Perhaps `--param max-rtl-if-conversion-predictable-cost=something` or `max-rtl-if-conversion-insns=something` or `max-rtl-if-conversion-unpredictable-cost=something` (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-fvect-cost-model).  The `-mtune=znver3` implied by `-march=znver3` presumably sets different values for those or other options than `-mtune=skylake` or the default `generic`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for your reply, in my real case, this vector is tiny, a few elements at most times, so I don't need SIMD. I have update the question, disable PRE works. Do you have better suggestions?

Comment: Hmm, with `-fno-tree-partial-pre`, it's back to the GCC8 behaviour of loading twice in the loop, instead of updating both index and value with `cmov`.  (This is probably actually better on modern x86 than 2x cmov, thanks to micro-fusion that lets `cmp   [rdx], edi` decode as a single uop, so the loop is 4 uops total on Broadwell and later, so they can run it at 1 iteration per cycle.)

Comment: Anyway, this seems like a missed-optimization bug you could report to GCC's bugzilla (with that keyword).  https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/.  Although for larger arrays, branch *could* be better because a new `max` will be rare.  OTOH, GCC's branchy code-gen has two *taken* branches in the no-new-max case, so it's backwards.  Hopefully PGO helps.

Comment: Oh, and for large arrays, GCC8's code has a loop-carried dependency involving the load address, `rdx`!  So that extra load which saves an instruction is very bad for big arrays, creating a latency bottleneck of 5 cycle load-use latency plus CMP + CMOV latency, 1 iteration per 7 cycles through RDX.  GCC's `-march=znver3` branchless code with 2x `cmov` avoids this problem, same as clangs.  So for your case, great, if out-of-order exec can hide the latency here for tiny arrays, the GCC8 (or GCC12 `-fno-tree-partial-pre`) code-gen is good.  Otherwise it's a disaster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a tuning choice / cost-model heuristic<sup>1</sup>.  As @HolyBlackCat noticed, `-march=znver3` (which implies the same `-mtune`) uses 2x `cmovb` to update the value and the pointer.  ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCAAnKQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BekkpjgJBIeEsUTHxdpgOaUIETMQEGT5%2BXLaY9nkM1bUEBWGR0XG2NXUNWc0KQ93BvcX9sQCUtqhexMjsHOYAzMHI3lgA1CYbbgBuFUTEh9gmGgCCm9u7mAdHyOP4gpfXd2ZbDDte%2B0ObjEwBIhAQLE%2Bty%2BXmCBA2ZgA%2BgQ9jQGOhESxghA0Axxns3iAQKcHCQgbDBAjkZ8zAA2PbHOZfEwAdistz2nL2xEwBGWDAJBHQRPw40MqwgxwAdFFgNiFoLhSAsQxEa1MGxBJKZZg5QwIArpa4DXMmRt2XcWQARL4cBa0TgAVl4fg4WlIqE4bms1gJSxWT02PFIBE0doWAGsQAipZINrTHQAODQpjYbFkbRMbfScSQusMezi8BQgDQhsMLOCwJBoFgJOjRciUWv1%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%2BW5rke907nuB4OEeJ6MGeF5Xu6t73o%2Bz5HlgClGF%2Bv2/mceAAQWwGgeBRGQQ634wXBCEYGs7ooWhGF8NhuEnQR528PwJGiOIFEk1RKjqN%2BuhmPoH5MZY1isRE%2BmcdxaR8QJQkiUKYmmMzliyfJinKRsVpqRpGy8Np0S6Zg7OGZDzgQK4UUWeisU2c0OT2ekfmjIkdntNr7nK0FPn1Ib5mBe0Vtm%2BFgxdBrYp1I7KWLMsyUNaNzoTQWmXZbl%2BWFcVpV7V1exVfg5x1RsDVNRWkbRhsFVphnmeZ6N42TbLRa2LNzVaK1SNmOlU0F8X4akBpKTOJIQA)).  `-march=icelake-server` or even `-march=sapphirerapids` still makes branchy asm.

That branchless asm is probably better on Broadwell and later as well, if the branch doesn't predict well, so this might be worth reporting on https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/ with a "missed-optimization" keyword, especially if you test it for non-tiny array sizes and find it is faster.

---

Hopefully profile-guided optimization (PGO: `-fprofile-generate` / test run / `-fprofile-use`) will make a good choice of branchy vs. branchless based on the actual predictability of your data.  Perhaps it's optimizing for large arrays on the assumption that a new `max` will be rare (which would be true for uniformly distributed random values.)  But it laid out the branch so it's taken in that case, vs. putting the block of `mov` instructions out-of-line.   Related: [gcc optimization flag -O3 makes code slower than -O2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28875325) re: branchy vs. branchless where branchless was slower because the condition *was* predictable; PGO helped there, if I recall.  (And where GCC's branchless asm had longer dependency chains than necessary.)

---

**GCC8's branchless code-gen would be bad for non-tiny arrays,** so it's a good thing modern GCC doesn't ever make that.  Notice that it only uses one `cmov` to update a pointer, and *loads from that conditionally-updated pointer in the `cmp`*.  So the load address next iteration depends on the compare + cmov this iteration.  As uiCA [shows us](https://uica.uops.info/?code=.L6%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mov%20%20%20%20%20edi%2C%20DWORD%20PTR%20%5Brdx%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20cmp%20%20%20%20%20DWORD%20PTR%20%5Brax%5D%2C%20edi%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20cmovb%20%20%20rdx%2C%20rax%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20add%20%20%20%20%20rax%2C%204%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20cmp%20%20%20%20%20rcx%2C%20rax%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20jne%20%20%20%20%20.L6&syntax=asIntel&uArchs=SKL&tools=uiCA&alignment=0), this data dependency creates a latency bottleneck of 7 cycles per iteration.

In C terms, it's like `biggest_ptr = (*ptr > *biggest_ptr) ? ptr : biggest_ptr;`

`-fno-tree-partial-pre` gives you that one-`cmov` GCC8 code-gen.  (Which is fine for your case where out-of-order exec can hide the latency so the execution overlaps with surrounding code.)  It's a disaster for larger arrays.

---

GCC12's branchless asm with two `cmovb` instructions only uses the updated max-value in the next iteration, not the pointer.  So the pointer-update cmov is part of a loop-carried dependency chain that's only 1 cycle long.  But the value-update `cmovb` forms a chain with `cmp  esi, ecx`, for a total latency bottleneck of 2 cycles per iteration.  (uiCA has a dependency graph visualizer that was helpful in noticing why it wasn't 1 cycle [for that version](https://uica.uops.info/?code=.L4%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mov%20%20%20%20%20esi%2C%20DWORD%20PTR%20%5Brdx%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20cmp%20%20%20%20%20esi%2C%20ecx%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20cmovb%20%20%20ecx%2C%20esi%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20cmovb%20%20%20rax%2C%20rdx%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20add%20%20%20%20%20rdx%2C%204%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20cmp%20%20%20%20%20r8%2C%20rdx%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20jne%20%20%20%20%20.L4%0D%0A&syntax=asIntel&uArchs=SKL&uArchs=ICL&tools=uiCA&alignment=0&uiCAHtmlOptions=dependencies).)

[uiCA predicts](https://uica.uops.info/?code=.L4%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mov%20%20%20%20%20ecx%2C%20DWORD%20PTR%20%5Brdx%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20cmp%20%20%20%20%20ecx%2C%20esi%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20jnb%20%20%20%20%20.L3%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mov%20%20%20%20%20esi%2C%20ecx%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mov%20%20%20%20%20rax%2C%20rdx%0D%0A.L3%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20add%20%20%20%20%20rdx%2C%204%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20cmp%20%20%20%20%20r8%2C%20rdx%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20jne%20%20%20%20%20.L4&syntax=asIntel&uArchs=SKL&uArchs=ICL&uArchs=RKL&tools=uiCA&alignment=0&uiCAHtmlOptions=dependencies) the branchy version can run at 1.33 cycles per iteration on Rocket Lake assuming perfect branch prediction.  (Which is like Ice Lake but with mov-elimination not disabled.)  It predicts 2.0 cycles / iter on Skylake and Ice Lake, but doesn't explain why.  Its RKL prediction might only make sense when there's a new `max` every iteration.  Its counts assume that the `mov` instructions actually ran.  But on Skylake, it's saying first cmp/jcc can only run on port 6, not port 0, which would only be true if it was taken.  uiCA (and other tools like IACA and I think LLVM-MCA) only really work well for branchless loops so I'm not sure this is meaningful.

---

**Footnote 1**:  GCC has a `--param` option to tune the knobs on internal heuristics.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html  I wouldn't recommend manually playing with these except as an experiment, but that's probably one of the answers to your question about whether there's any GCC option to change the code-gen.

`--param max-rtl-if-conversion-predictable-cost=something`, `max-rtl-if-conversion-insns=something` or `max-rtl-if-conversion-unpredictable-cost=something` are probably relevant since if-conversion (to branchless) is the optimization in question.

The `-mtune=znver3` implied by `-march=znver3` presumably sets different values for those or other options than `-mtune=skylake` or the default `generic`.