# How can I perform a branchless conditional arithmetic operation in C?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, micro-optimization, twos-complement, branchless

I have a value `int x` where I want to conditionally add (for example) a value `int y` to, contingent on `bool c`. I could write code like this:

```
bool c;    // C23, or stdbool.h macro for _Bool.  Converts to integer 0 or 1
int x, y;  // x could be a global or something

...

if (c)
    x += y;
```

How could I write this without a branch?

If `x` is a local variable that no other thread could have a reference to, compilers may do if-conversion to branchless if they think that's more efficient.  (Especially if auto-vectorizing, but also for scalar.)  But that wouldn't be thread-safe for global variables, or if `x` is actually `*x` with an `int *`.  Compilers can't invent writes like `*x += 0` to possibly-shared objects that the abstract machine doesn't read or write, that could introduce a data race and step on values stored by other threads.

Comment: How about `x += c*y`?

Comment: @MehdiCharife: That's one option.  And it's simple so compilers are likely to be able to turn it into something more efficient, like an x86 `cmov` to actually implement `x += c ? y : 0`, instead of actually multiplying.  Especially if compiling for CPUs without extremely efficient multiply units, especially for 64-bit integers.  https://godbolt.org/z/YoM65v41K shows GCC turning the multiply into `neg`/`and`, the same bithack proposed in the OP's self-answer.  But clang using `test`/`cmov` with the `bool` itself as a source of a zero.

Comment: @MehdiCharife True isn't 1, it's any non zero value.  So if c is 2, it would evaluate to true, but your idea would add 2*y instead of y

Comment: @GabeSechan: The question specified `bool c`.  ISO C guarantees that conversion from `bool` to an integral type produces `0` or `1`.  That would be a problem for a 0/non-0 condition in another `int`, but not for `_Bool`.

Comment: Is `c` exactly 0 or 1? If so, Medhi's solution will work. And what are the types of `x`, `y`, and `c`?

Comment: @CraigEstey The types are specified in the question: `int x`, `int y`, `bool c`

Comment: `typedef int bool;`???

Comment: @MattTimmermans: Not if `x` is actually a reference or global.  It's not thread-safe for a compiler to invent writes, so `x += 0` would introduce a data race and could step on writes by other threads (unless done using x86 `lock add` for example, which costs more than a branch mispredict).  You're right that if-conversion to branchless is likely if `x` actually is a local var that the compiler knows no other threads can have references to.

Comment: @CraigEstey More like `#define bool _Bool` courtesy of C99 and `<stdbool.h>`.

Comment: @CraigEstey: I think it's reasonable to assume `#include <stdbool.h>` so `typedef _Bool bool`.  Correction, it's specified as a macro, `#define bool _Bool`.  Until C23, when `bool`, `true`, and `false` become keywords.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/arithmetic_types#Boolean_type

Comment: Or since C23, just `bool` :-)

Comment: `x += c ? y : 0` will optimize to a branchless conditional move

Comment: does `c` have `bool` type or it can be anything which can be used in `if` in C (pointer, integer etc)?

Comment: @thebusybee have you seen `if(ptr) do_somethin();` BTW C90 does not ha bool.

Comment: Technically, @PeterCordes, it's the other way around.  ISO C guarantees that any conversion *to* `_Bool` produces either 0 or 1.  That does make it hard to have a `_Bool` with a value different from both 0 and 1, but not impossible.

Comment: @0___________ And, is `c` a `bool`? What do you want to say?

Comment: @thebusybee I do not know what you are writing about. `If` can work with anything which can be converted to integer not only type `bool`

Comment: How do you define "branchless"? It depends on the target system if a branch is compiled. Some processors have conditional operations other than branches, other do not. Do you mean a non-conditional on the C level? Please clarify.

Comment: @0___________ I try to find out what you mean in **your** comment.

Comment: @thebusybee Any code whose compiler output could result in a conditional jump instruction.

Comment: @user16217248 Sure, it depends on the target **and** the compiler's capabilities. That's why I ask the OP to clarify.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Oh, my mistake, you're right `_Bool` has values `0` or `1`, not separate `false` / `true`.  Until C23 when the names of its possible values become `false` and `true` like in C++ https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/arithmetic_types#Boolean_type, so only conversion to integer produces `0` / `1`, if I understand correctly.  It's still technically correct to say that conversion from `_Bool` to an integral type does produces `0` or `1`, even if those were already the source value (pre-C23), so I think my edit to the question is correct enough :P

Comment: @PeterCordes I think your edit was about compilers refraining to optimize the code in the question into a branchless version if it thinks doing so is potentially unsafe, like if the memory is not a local variable and could be accessed by other threads. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. That paragraph I added at the end was for the benefit of other future readers who were thinking the compiler would do this for them.  (Which it might in cases when it's allowed, e.g. [gcc optimization flag -O3 makes code slower than -O2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28875325) shows a case where if-conversion hurts, especially since GCC did it poorly, making the loop-carried dependency chain longer than necessary.)  Matt Timmermans had commented that compilers would do this; he's since deleted the comment after my reply or edit, but other future readers might think the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A basic answer would be to produce a branchless expression that evaluates to `y` if `c` is `true` or to the identity of the operation (0 for addition/subtraction and 1 for multiplication/division) otherwise and then use that expression.

### Option 1: [Multiplication by the boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77123392/how-can-i-perform-a-branchless-conditional-arithmetic-operation-in-c/77123393#comment135959678_77123392)

A very simple solution is simply multiply the boolean with `y` then add:

```
x += c*y;
```

### Option 2: Bitwise logic

Create a mask from the boolean, bitwise and, then add:

```
x += -c&y;
```

This way, if the boolean is false, negating the value will still be 0, and bitwise and 0 with any number gives zero, so this will result in adding 0 to the value. Otherwise, negating `true` would give `-1` which is all 1s in 2's complement, which would give the `y` back from the bitwise and, adding `y` to `x`.

**Note:** The question uses addition as an example, but if the operation in question is division or multiplication, the value `!c` must be added to the right-hand operand of the augmented assignment. This is because the multiplicative identity is 1 and not 0.

E.g.

```
x *= -c&y+!c;
```

Comment: What if `c` is a not null pointer?

Comment: @0___________ `c` was specified in the question to have type `bool` which means that it is guaranteed to have value 0 or 1.

Comment: @0___________ And converting a value to `bool` type has the same effect as `!!`.

Comment: Try to convert in C90

Comment: @0___________ C90 does not have `bool` or `_Bool` so I would have to use `!!` or `!= 0`.

Comment: @0___________ You're the only one who's said anything about the ancient C90 language.  The question specifies `bool c` (and did so even before my edit), which tells us it's not asking about C90.  If you want to post an answer about the general case where `c` could have a different type and show how to booleanize to 0 or 1, that's fine, but it's not a mistake for other answers to assume that's already been done.

Comment: Note: It has to be `-` and not `~` because `~1` is `-2` and not `-1`. This would disregard the LSB of `y`.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/vobv876Mv shows both of these, and the standard `x += c ? y : 0` ternary. (Actually with `*x` so the compiler couldn't do if-conversion to branchless on its own without inventing writes, or with Intel APX or ARM predication for a scalar conditional store insn.)  Interestingly, GCC compiles `x += c*y` to `neg` / `and` instead of a `cmov`.  And GCC [still](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28875325/224132) pessimizes `*x += c ? y : 0` to `*x = c ? *x+y : *x;` so there's a cmov on the critical path through the `*x` input instead of just in the chain creating input to the `+`.  (

Comment: As a side note, multiplication might be slower than having a branch on low- to mid-range CPUs (no cache, no branch prediction, maybe pipelining) - on those systems we do not typically optimize away branching in the first place. But if you are looking for truly portable code for many different targets, then the bitwise logic version is more likely to generate efficient code.

Comment: Re: multiplying by a `bool`: apparently this was GCC bug https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=68557 - reported 2015, with the suggestion of the `neg`/`and` sequence.  It was eventually closed-fixed in 2022.  It seems I commented on it in 2016 re: throughput vs. latency with `imul` being 1 uop vs. neg/and being 2.  I didn't mention `cmov`, perhaps since it wouldn't have been as helpful there, and Intel CPUs with single-uop CMOV were still newish at that point.

Answer (score 4):

Compilers can do this for you without you changing the source code, on some architectures.

A short (and concise) example (for ARM):

```c
#include <stdbool.h>

int foo(bool c, int x, int y)
{
    if (c)
        x += y;
    return x;
}
```

```asm
foo:
        mla     r0, r2, r0, r1
        bx      lr
```

https://godbolt.org/z/PzEedYc8P

Comment: This kind of thing is what my edit to the question was referencing, with "*compilers may do if-conversion to branchless if they think that's more efficient*.  (Interesting that it uses an actual multiply, rather than `tst` and `it ne` / `addne` predication, since ARM has multiply-accumulate as a single insn that isn't slow on most cores).  Note that it's only possible of `x` is a local variable whose address hasn't escaped, not a global or a placeholder for `*x`, or anything else that some other thread could be writing at the same time.

Comment: +1 for doing arm and showing (as I surmised) that doing the simple/straightforward `if` would optimize to branchless.

Comment: Interesting ... I ran your code on a gcc linaro aarch64 cross-compiler 7.5.0 for armv8a with -O3 and I get `tst w0, 255 ; add w0, w1, w2 ; csel w0, w0, w1, ne ; ret`

Comment: If I tweak your Godbolt example to shift compiler from trunk to 13.2.0, then gcc doesn't do the optimization any longer. This seems to be brittle and should not be relied upon. Similar results for ARM64 trunk vs ARM64 13.2.0.

Comment: @Lundin: Agreed; at least write it with a ternary (`x += c ? y : 0`) if you expect branchless code to be more efficient.  That's pretty readable and idiomatic.   Interestingly, when the `if` condition is something like `a>b` instead of an actual `bool` function arg, GCC13.2 does make branchless code for ARM and AArch64, with add/cmp/csel unfortunately.  https://godbolt.org/z/e9nbM89qx  (Even pessimizing the ternary to `x = a>b ? x+y : x`, unlike clang which uses csel off the critical path from `x` input to output, to generate a y or 0 as written)

Answer (score 0):

`c` can have any value in C language (unless it has the type `bool`) and you need to normalize it to `0` or `1`

```
x += (!!c) * y;
```

Comment: godbolt links [here](https://www.godbolt.org/z/hPsGnY4av) and [here](https://www.godbolt.org/z/hPsGnY4av) for gcc and msvc

Comment: But, `c` _is_ a `bool`

Comment: @TedLyngmo it is more universal and same efficient.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: In that case `!!` will optimize away.  https://godbolt.org/z/sMYPvse1s

Comment: @PeterCordes Sure, but it seems redundant. We want a `bool` and we already have a `bool`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Yes, better phrasing for this answer would be "in the general case where `c` could have a type other than `bool`, we can booleanize it to 0 or 1 first:" .  The answer was posted without even the parenthetical note but then edited within the grace period after the author noticed what the question actually said to make it only minimally less silly.

Comment: @PeterCordes what do you mean by silly?

Comment: The question says `c` is a `bool`.  Your answer contradicts the question, and posts code with a `!!c` which is redundant for the question as asked.  If you want to answer a more general question (for other types of `c`), explain that's what you're doing, instead of contradicting how the question is actually asked.  (Sometimes a quesiton makes an unreasonable that should get corrected, but that's not the case here.)

Comment: And in modern standard C we'd probably prefer to write `(bool)c * y` in case `c` is some numerical value larger than 1.