# Why is using a foreach loop 3 times slower than using an indexed loop in Visual C++?

Tags: arrays, visual-c++, foreach, compiler-optimization

In reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809) famous StackOverflow question, I ran the provided code with [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com) 2022 17.8.0. Preview 2.0 in x64 release mode.

```
>cl
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.38.33030 for x64
```

My results were quite surprising.

- Using std::sort: ~3s
- Not using std::sort: ~3s (!)

Branch prediction failure did not make any more difference!

Furthermore, I refactored the code to use a foreach loop as its inner processing loop as follows:

```
for (int c : data)
{   // Primary loop.
    if (c >= 128)
        sum += c;
}
```

Previous code:

```
for (unsigned c = 0; c < array_size; ++c)
{   // Primary loop.
    if (data[c] >= 128)
        sum += data[c];
}
```

Now the results were drastically different:

- Using std::sort: ~9s (!)
- Not using std::sort: ~36s (!)

It looks like using the foreach loop disabled loop optimizations which included branch prediction failures. Either Microsoft hardcoded this famous question to show that their compiler improved or that seems quite a coincidence.

The difference in generated code becomes clear as well when decompiling using IDA Pro:

**"Slow" version:**

```
int __cdecl main(int argc, const char **argv, const char **envp)
{
  int *v3; // rbx
  __int64 v4; // rbx
  __int64 v5; // r8
  int *v6; // rcx
  __int64 v7; // rdx
  std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> > *v8; // rax
  char v9; // dl
  const char *v10; // rdx
  std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> > *v11; // rax
  std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> > *v12; // rax
  char v13; // dl
  int _First; // [rsp+20h] [rbp-20018h]
  int _Last[2]; // [rsp+20020h] [rbp-18h]

  v3 = &_First;
  do
  {
    *v3 = rand() % 256;
    ++v3;
  }
  while ( v3 != _Last );
  std::_Sort_unchecked<int *,std::less<void>>(&_First, _Last, 0x8000i64, 0);
  clock();
  v4 = 0i64;
  v5 = 100000i64;
  do
  {
    v6 = &_First;
    do
    {
      v7 = *v6;
      if ( (int)v7 >= 128 )
        v4 += v7;
      ++v6;
    }
    while ( v6 != _Last );
    --v5;
  }
  while ( v5 );
  clock();
  v8 = (std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> > *)std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator<<(std::cout);
  std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char>>(v8, v9);
  v11 = std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::cout, v10);
  v12 = (std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> > *)std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator<<(
                                                              v11,
                                                              v4);
  std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char>>(v12, v13);
  return 0;
}
```

The 100000 iterations are kept as in the original code.

**"Fast" version:**

```
int __cdecl main(int argc, const char **argv, const char **envp)
{
  int *v3; // rbx
  __int64 v4; // rdi
  __int64 v5; // rbx
  int *v6; // r8
  __int64 v7; // rcx
  __int64 v8; // rdx
  std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> > *v9; // rax
  char v10; // dl
  const char *v11; // rdx
  std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> > *v12; // rax
  std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> > *v13; // rax
  char v14; // dl
  int _First; // [rsp+20h] [rbp-20018h]
  int _Last[2]; // [rsp+20020h] [rbp-18h]

  v3 = &_First;
  do
  {
    *v3 = rand() % 256;
    ++v3;
  }
  while ( v3 != _Last );
  v4 = 0x8000i64;
  std::_Sort_unchecked<int *,std::less<void>>(&_First, _Last, 0x8000i64, 0);
  clock();
  v5 = 0i64;
  v6 = &_First;
  do
  {
    v7 = *v6;
    v8 = 20000i64;
    do
    {
      if ( (int)v7 >= 128 )
        v5 += v7 + v7 + v7 + v7 + v7;
      --v8;
    }
    while ( v8 );
    ++v6;
    --v4;
  }
  while ( v4 );
  clock();
  v9 = (std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> > *)std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator<<(std::cout);
  std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char>>(v9, v10);
  v12 = std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::cout, v11);
  v13 = (std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> > *)std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator<<(
                                                              v12,
                                                              v5);
  std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char>>(v13, v14);
  return 0;
}
```

Here we see some more clever inlining of computations to reduce loop iterations.

Why does a foreach loop instead of an indexed loop make such a difference in optimizations? Aren't both loops basically semantically equivalent? [Resharper C++](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper-cpp), a refactoring tool, suggested this equivalent refactoring.

I've also been told that [using abstractions doesn't cost](https://medium.com/@rahulchakraborty337/zero-cost-abstraction-in-c-fbc9be45772b) and that abstractions help the compiler to find better optimizations, but the opposite seems to be happening here.

**EDIT:**
It seems like these issues don't apply when e.g. compiling with the [Intel C++ Compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_C%2B%2B_Compiler). It has none of these performance issues and in fact even generates vectorized code which MSVC refuses to generate. This cuts the runtime down to ~1.6s. It's a bit disappointing that the MSVC team seems to not be doing a great job here.

Comment: Yes, good compilers will make branchless asm (like GCC at `-O3`, although that can be harmful for the sorted case if it does it badly: [gcc optimization flag -O3 makes code slower than -O2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28875325)).  Or clang will auto-vectorize even with just SSE2 although it's more profitable with SSE4 or especially AVX2.  https://godbolt.org/z/ha3f8endc .  MSVC doesn't even with `-arch:AVX2`

Comment: And yeah, MSVC is doing [loop interchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_interchange) to defeat the benchmark repeat count (so only one branch mispredict per `100000` `add` instructions).  But not rolling it up into `sum += data[c]*100000;`.